# Salesforce to Box integration

Tags: apex, integration

I'm trying to create folder in box when a file is attached through show feed on a salesforce record (say -object 'LEad'), which is having a text field 'Box Link' on Lead Record. It will have 'folder id' in box in which the attachment has to be created. if the field is null, create a new folder, and save the attachment in new folder. Please suggest. I've tried

created a trigger on feeditem and passing ids here in the below handler class.

```
    public class feedItemtrigger_Handler {
     public string clientId;
     public String clientSecret;
     public String redirecturi {
      Set;
      get;
     }
     public string code {
      set;
      get;
     }
     public String folderId;
     public String accessToken {
      set;
      get;
     }
     public String folderInfo {
      Set;
      get;
     }

     /* public feedItemtrigger_Handler(){
          //'https://ap5.salesforce.com/apex/BoxResponsePage';
          redirectUri='https://ap4.developer--c.cs44.visual.force.com/apex/BoxResponse?core.apexpages.request.devconsole=1';
      }*/
     public PageReference requestCode() {
      clientId = BoxCCredentials__c.getValues('BoxTest').Client_Id__c;
      clientSecret = BoxCCredentials__c.getValues('BoxTest').Client_Secret__C;
      redirectUri = 'https://ap4.developer--c.cs44.visual.force.com/apex/BoxResponse?core.apexpages.request.devconsole=1';
      String url = 'https://account.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?';
      url = url + 'response_type=code&client_id=' + clientId + '&redirect_uri=' + redirectUri + '&state=annnd';
      PageReference p = new PageReference(url);
      return p;
     }

     public void getCodes() {
      code = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('code');
     }

     public void requestAccessToken() {
      //String clientId = BoxCCredentials__c.getValues('BoxTest').Client_Id__c;
      code = 'gxpmpMG9zJGbQO4snDxSnm4Ho12dgncu ';
      Http p = new Http();
      String url = 'https://api.box.com/oauth2/token';
      String body = 'grant_type=authorization_code';
      body = body + '&client_id=' + clientId;
      body = body + '&client_secret=' + clientSecret;
      body = body + '&code=' + code;
      HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
      request.setEndPoint(url);
      request.setMethod('POST');
      request.setBody(body);
      HttpResponse response = p.send(request);
      System.JSONParser jp = JSON.createParser(response.getBody());
      while (jp.nextToken() != null) {
       if (jp.getText() == 'access_token') {
        jp.nextToken();
        accessToken = jp.getText();
       }
      }
     }

     @future(callout = true)
     public static void CreateFolder(List < ID > FeedIDs) {

      List < FeedItem > feeditemlist = [Select Id, ParentId, (SELECT RecordId, Title, type, Value FROM FeedAttachments), Type, Title, Body, CommentCount, LikeCount, LinkUrl, RelatedRecordId, parent.type From FeedItem where id in : FeedIDs];
      system.debug('feeditemList---->' + feeditemlist);
      map < id, id > feeditemparentmap = new map < id, id > ();
      List < Id > LoanIDs = new List < ID > ();

      for (FeedItem feeditemobj: feeditemlist) {
       LoanIDs.add(feeditemobj.parentid);
      }
      system.debug('feeditemparentmap---->' + feeditemparentmap);

      map < id, Loan__c > loanMap = new map < id, loan__c > ([select id, name, Box_folder_link__c from Loan__c where id in : LoanIDs]);
      for (FeedItem feeditemobj: feeditemlist) {
       Loan__C loanrecord = loanMap.get(feeditemparentmap.get(feeditemobj.id));
       if (loanrecord.Box_folder_link__c == null) {
        //create folder
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        //req.setEndpoint('https://tfstest01.amtote.com/tfs/tfs2010/TFS_Tote');
        req.setEndPoint('https://api.box.com/2.0/folders');
        req.setmethod('POST');
        req.setBody('{"name":"TestFolder", "parent": {"id": "0"}}');
        //req.setHeader('content-type','application/json');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);

        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        System.debug(res.getBody());

        if (res.getstatuscode() == 200) {
         string folderId;
         System.JSONparser jp = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
         while (jp.nextToken() != null) {
          if (jp.getText() == 'id') {
           jp.nextToken();
           folderId = jp.getText();
          }
         }
         loanrecord.Box_folder_link__c = res.getBody();
         update loanrecord;
        }
       }

      }


     }

    }
```

Comment: Being new to integration, This is what i've tried so far.

Comment: Where are you stuck? It's hard to help you improve when we don't know why your current code doesn't meet your needs. Are you hitting an error? If so please **[edit]** your post to include its message ***verbatim***.